# How to get Lat Lng coordinates from PlacePicker and place it on Map Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am implementing `MapsActivity` and `PlacePicker`.I had put the `Placepicker` implementation method in `getMapReady` function.

When I run it, first a placepicker comes and asks to select the certain location then it goes to mylocation but not the placepicker selected location.

Anyone have idea on this.
I have tried `LatLngBounds` but not successful.Thanks.

Comment: show me your onActivityResult() where you have implemented the code for placepicker's function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have tried as below:

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Here, get the position of the place, mark it in map and moveCamera to that, couple lines of code. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have this on my code. But that selected place doesn't show up on Mapsactivity. For example,in placepicker if i selected place A and tap it , it goes to mylocation not to the place A

Comment: how to get the position of the place?If I get the position,i can moveCamera to that place.Am i right ?

Comment: You can use: `place.getLatLng()` to get the latitude and longitude as posittion and then use addMarker(new MarkerOptions( ... )) then you can move camera.

Comment: Thank you very much Pavan. It worked. Today, I learned something new.